# Java Https default retry mechanism

Tags: java, https, connection

Is there a default retry when using sun HttpsUrlConnection ?
If so, how can I cancel it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remeber correctly, the Sun VM, up to Java 1.4, attempted to retry HTTP/HTTPS requests once if the first request failed with some specific error conditions. Since Java 5, this is not done anymore.

It was not possible to disable this behaviour in Java 1.4, so if you're stuck with an old Java VM and cannot accept this behaviour, you have to use a 3rd party HTTP library, like [HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) from Apache.

Comment: I think I am still seeing this behavior in Java 7's SunJSSE.